# Can I make a Xamarin.Form app (iOS) support Apple Dynamic Type?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Apple iOS Settings > Display & Brightness there is the ability to change the size of text for applications that use Dynamic Type.

Is it possible to do this with Xamarin.Forms app (iOS custom rendere maybe).  If so can someone give an example of how to do this for something like a TableSection Heading and a Label?

Comment: not sure what "Label" you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS you need for XF TableView TableViewRenderer with native control of UITableView. More here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers/

To avoid duplicated answer I will just provide a link

[With a custom renderer can I make a TableSection.Title appear in small mixed case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45622532/with-a-custom-renderer-can-i-make-a-tablesection-title-appear-in-small-mixed-cas/45626725)